# How to wait for fn component to load to read containing anchor IDs to enable correct navigation

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, web-component

I have a React app that contains multiple tabs, which are lazy-loaded separate apps. The overarching app sets the tabs and the loaded apps have section anchors that can be navigated between tabs.

My issue is, as the anchors only load with the `ImportedComponent`, the `useEffect` cannot find the anchor with the first render, only subsequent renders. Any suggestions?

```
const Tab3 = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    linkToComponentSection(anchor); 
    }, 
  [anchor]);

  return (
    <ImportedComponent />
  )
}
```

```
const ImportedComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Title />
      <a id={anchorLinkForTab3} />
    </>
  )
}
```

The only solution I have found is to wrap the contents of the useEffect in a setTimeout, which works but isn't ideal.

I considered not using lazy loading but this also isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to solve this with a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).
When the observer detects that the content of the tab has changed you can execute your callback to navigate/scroll/jump to the anchor.
(I have not tried this before; but I sucessfully wrapped both ResizeObserver and IntersectionObserver in custom react hooks and use them ever since.)

Comment: Thanks Martin! This looks like it will do the job - I will give it a try and report back :)

Comment: This worked thanks Martin! For anyone else watching here is some references https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/use-mutation-observer/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @stussl Great to hear that. Did you use the 30secondsofcode implementation or did you create your own?

Comment: We created our own, using that as a starting point. I've posted below for reference! Thanks again for you help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The below is the hook that worked utilising `MutationObserver`:

```
const mutationObserver = (
  anchorId: string | undefined,
): void => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
      const renderedAnchor = anchorId && document.getElementById(anchorId);
      if (renderedAnchor) {
        linkToComponentSection(anchorId);
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });

    observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });

    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  }, [anchorId]);
};
```